# Sending to a specific person in address

Tags: terminology

How do I specify on an address that it should be forwarded to some person?

Sometimes I need to send mail to a company where it should be addressed to a specific person, but it's not the 'address name', another example I have a friend in the US who comes to visit me (outside the US) often, and I want to ship items to him but he should know it's for me and I want to specify it on the mail address.

Is the word just 'for John Doe' or it's been thought out and a word's been made up for it?

Comment: After the line with the company name, you place on its own line : "Attention: John Doe" or "Attn.: John Doe". See this link: http://jobsearchtech.about.com/od/letters/l/bl_block_p.htm

Comment: You simply put the person's name on a line right above the "normal" part of the address.  http://jobsearchtech.about.com/od/letters/l/bl_envelope.htm

Comment: @JLG- Too funny :-)

Comment: @Jim, I'd say Shimmy now knows how to format both business letters and envelopes.

Comment: There might also be a local convention that should be observed. In the country where I live now, putting the person's name above the company name means for attention of that person only, while putting it below the company name means it can be opened by an assistant or colleague. Or is it the other way round - I can never remember? Safest to include 'Private' or 'Personal' if it really is.

Comment: Attn: and FAO: used to be more a matter of internal forwarding.

Comment: Hi everyone. I just used an example in my post, I didn't know it may change the whole context. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK, I would use [***care of***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/care_of), abbreviated to ***c/o***, for either a person...

```
 Joe Bloggs
 c/o John Smith
 London Road
 Blighty
```

...or company.

```
 Joe Bloggs
 c/o Big Corp
 London Road
 Blighty
```

Comment: We'd only do that if Joe Bloggs didn't live with John Smith, or work at Big Corp.

Comment: You could also use it for someone who doesn't usually reside with John Smith, but does at that moment. For the latter case, sure, but the question specified "forwarded". The question should be made clearer if that isn't the case.

Comment: Or I suppose if it wasn't work related. I do use ℅ with personal deliveries to my office as it's polite to distinguish that from business mail, along with a convenience to see which are which.

Comment: Is it also applicable in the US?

Comment: @Shimmy Yes - a little searching reveals that this is also used in the US.